# Reading a Private DSA Key for signing

Tags: c, go

I am new to golang and want to implement a functionality from my olde C-Program.

I have a "DSA PRIVATE KEY" with passphrase and a "CERTIFICATE"

In C I did:

```
{
char *privkey=
  "-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n"
  "DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC, xxxxxx\n"
  "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
  "xxxx\n"
  "Og==\n"
  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
;
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(mem, privkey);
dsa = PEM_read_bio_DSAPrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, "passphrase");

Byte hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
unsigned int hashLen = EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE;
EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, EVP_dss1(), NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, data, dataLen);
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, hash, &hashLen);
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);

Byte signatur[1024];
memset(signatur, 0, 1024);
char buf[200];
short fehler = 0;
signaturLen = DSA_size(dsa);
fehler = !DSA_sign(0, hash, hashLen, signatur, &signaturLen, dsa);
if (fehler) {
  ps("FEHLER: signieren gescheitert");
  ps(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buf));
}

// do something with signatur

DSA_free(dsa);
}
```

and it worked as expected. how do I achieve this with golang? I tried

```
func (s SignConfig) ReadPrivateKey() (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
  b, e := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join(core.ConfigDir(), s.PrivateKey))
  if e != nil {
    return nil, e
  }

  block, _ := pem.Decode(b)
  b, e = x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte(s.PassPhrase))
  priv, e := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(b)

  if e != nil {
    return nil, e
  }

  return priv, nil
}
```

to read the private key, but I got `asn1.StructuralError{Msg:"integer too large"}`

Comment: The error is because you're trying to treat a DSA key as an RSA key. There's no code to work with DSA keys in the go crypto library or the ssh package, probably because they've been deprecated and not really used much for many years.

Comment: Here's an explanation from AGL showing how to determine the key structure to `asn1.Unmarshal` into: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/0WLCbeG1vfY/discussion with a working example: http://play.golang.org/p/2IbFYl9WBD

Comment: @JimB is there a tool to convert the "DSA key file" into a RSA file?

Comment: It's not a matter of converting a format, DSA and RSA are different things with different capabilities.